# Octave library error when reading in data (FSL PALM)

Tags: octave

I am running FSL PALM via Octave (v.5.2.0) from Ubuntu 20.04. I installed Octave [per these instructions](https://brainder.org/tag/palm/). I am encountering this error from **Octave**, which I think it related to a package dependency (`liboctinterp.so.6`).

```
error: multifile2mat: /home/admin/Documents/palm-alpha119/fileio/@file_array/private/file2mat.mex: failed to load: liboctinterp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have found that others have had similar issues on different forums but have not seen that one as posted a working solution. I also tracked this path `/home/admin/Documents/palm-alpha119/fileio/@file_array/private/file2mat.mex` and the file does exist.

Has anyone encountered a working solution for this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello. Is the command you are running accessing a directory or trying to access a directory that the logged in user does not have permission to? Or file.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the Octave flatpak that you installed. FYI the Ubuntu 20.04 repository already contains Octave 5.2.0-1 so the premise of the article (*"stable Linux distributions ... still offer only 3.8.2 in the official repositories at the time of this writing"*) is no longer the case - you might have better luck removing the flatpak and installing the native Ubuntu Octave (which depends on liboctave7 and provides liboctinterp.so.7)

Comment: How did you install octave?

Comment: @David The command I am running should have access to this directory -- the file it is trying to read in is accessible by the user and the other directory needed to read in the file should also be accessible. How can I check otherwise?

Comment: @steeldriver That is good to know... I deinstalled flatpak then deinstalled and reinstalled octave. I still get this error and it calls liboctinterp.so.6 still... When reinstalling, shouldn't it automatically take the newest library version?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi please see the link in the original post. Since then, I have deinstalled this (comment above) and reinstalled it. And still have the error.

Comment: @AftonNelson The link mentions both apt and flatpak. What did you use? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1400186/edit) the question and add the exact commands that you entered, instead of posting links.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi The link is specifically referring to flatpak... which is what I used... and also includes apt. For clarification: `sudo apt install flatpak` But as I mentioned above with relation to steeldriver's suggestion, I deinstalled and reinstalled only octave as one would usually do with `sudo apt install octave`.

Comment: How do you run FSL PALM? I would try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi That would be great! Thank you! (1) I downloaded [PALM](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/PALM/UserGuide) and unzipped the file. (2) Then, I opened Octave, and I added the path to the palm directory `addpath "home/admin/Documents/palm-alpha119")` .  (3) Then, I unzipped the input nii.gz file with gunzip `gunzip 4D_all.nii.gz`. (4) Then, I ran the palm command `palm -i /path/to/input/4D_all.nii -o palm_output -T -C 3.1 -n 5000 -save1-p`.  The error occurs somewhere inside palm after it has read in the input file when it tries to access the multifile2mat.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to reconfigure the various .mex files that PALM needs to run. The reconfiguration ensured that the files were compatible with my version of Octave (not the default version upon the download of PALM). This should be done through the .c file, not directly in the .mex file.

I did this using

```
cd /home/admin/Documents/palm-alpha119/fileio/@file_array/private
mex file2mat.c
```

In my case, I had to do this for multiple files from PALM before it was able to run all the way through. However, the running of PALM (5000 permutation) took a long time (ca. 4 hours) where as it runs in 15 minutes when executing the same command with randomise.

The post and working solution can be found [here](https://octave.discourse.group/t/error-when-running-fsl-palm-in-octave-5-2-0-failed-to-load-liboctinterp-so-6/2483).

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution.